# R: Data Frame is removing every other character from nvarchar/unicode fields

Tags: r, sql-server, database, odbc, sqldatatypes

I have connected R to my database using the below:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver   = "/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib",
                      Server   = "my server",
                      Database = "my db",
                      UID      = "my uid",
                      PWD      = "my pw",
                      Port     = 1433)
```

but for every string (either table names or field values), every even character has been removed.

Example 1-:

```
dbListTables(con)
```

Returns:

```
SLn
```

However, the actual table name is 'SOLine'

Example 2 - Running a query using:

```
query<-paste0("SELECT SOOrder.AddressLine1, SOOrder.OrderDate, SOOrder.OrderTotal FROM SOOrder WHERE SOOrder.OrderNbr=1")

test_query<-dbGetQuery(con,query)

test query
```

Returns:

```
AddressLine1    OrderDate    OrderTotal
Ts drs ie1     2019-10-28      100.00
```

When running the same query in SSMS returns:

```
AddressLine1             OrderDate    OrderTotal
Test Address Line 1     2019-10-28      100.00
```

Therefore, integers and date-time are not affected. It solely appears to be strings: more specifically nvarchar (varchar types are not affected). Looking into the schema, they are Unicode fields.

Answer (score 0):

Have not found a fix - but a good workaround is

`CAST(Table.Column AS varchar) AS Column`

This allows the complete column to successfully pull through.